# how to change a window border color in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a problem with changing the background of this part of the window:

[image]

How do I change it?

Comment: It is not possible

Comment: This part of the window is handled by windows, so it has nothing to do with Tkinter. So if you want change the color you can right click on desktop -->Personalize-->Color

Comment: @Module_art You didn't understand my question, I'm trying to create a function that changes the theme of this text editor in the picture. I have changed the textbox bg and fg and it works perfectly. But I don't know how to change the border color and it's kind of annoying me... So my question is if are there some ways to do so....

Comment: @roee1454 Which border? In coding 10 rows of code means more than 100 pictures. Maybe you show some

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are using windows.

This color is set by the theme you are currently using. It is the same for every window.

So I cross out the possibility of only using the Tkinter module for this.

Tkinter is responsible for what is in the window but the window manager decides about the border. For example in Ubuntu the window would look totally different.

I guess, you would need some windows specific calls for that.

You can remove the border with root.overrideredirect(1) if I remember correctly.
PS: put "windows" into the tags of this question.